# MySQL Table taking up too much space?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a raw text file, with the size of 8.1GB.
The input data is very straight forward:
Lab_A (string), Lab_B (string), Distance (float)

I was trying to load the data into a table, using LOAD DATA INFILE, but the drive ran out of space.

The destination table had the following format:

Id (INT), Lab_A (VARCHAR), Lab_B (VARCHAR), Distance (FLOAT).
With a primary key of Id and an index of (Lab_A + Distance).

Create statement below:

```
CREATE TABLE 'warwick_word_suite'.'distances' (
  'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'label1' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'label2' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'distance' FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  INDEX 'LABEL_INDEX' ('label1' ASC, 'distance' ASC));
```

The drive had 50GB and ran out of space. Given 10GB reserved for the system, I am assuming the table was requesting more than > 32GB for the table.

My question is:

- How much do InnoDB tables actually take up, relative to the size of the input data?
- Do indexed tables take up a lot more space, compared to identical unindexed tables?

Should I simply order a bigger drive for my database server?

EDIT:
I tracked down the data hog to "ibdata1", stored in /var/lib/mysql. This file is taking up 30.3GB.

Comment: Show us the 'SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]' statement.. MySQL has many string datatypes

Comment: @RaymondNijland I had updated the original question with a create statement.

Comment: Have you actually checked, what uses all that space? Have you seen a file that takes all that space? What logs do you have enabled? binary log? general log? slow log?

Comment: @fancyPants Thank you for the comment. It seems to be data related, as the 30.3GB is in an ibdata1 file in /var/lib/mysql/. I assume this file holds the actual database data of the tables?

Comment: Not only that, when you haven't set the file-per-table option, also the undo log and so on. Still it's strange. Can you execute this query to see, if it's really your table that's taking all the space? `select table_schema, table_name, (data_length+index_length)/1024/1024 as size_mb from information_schema.tables order by data_length + index_length desc limit 5;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double trouble.

InnoDB takes 2x-3x what the raw data takes.  This is a crude approximation; there are many factors.

`ibdata1` is the default place to put the table.  Having tried to put the table there, that file will not shrink.  This can be a problem.  It would have been better to have `innodb_file_per_table = ON` *before* trying to load the file.  Then the table would have gone into a separate `.ibd` file, and upon failure, that file would have vanished.  As it is, you are low on disk space with no simple way to recover it.  (Recovery includes dumping *all the other InnoDB tables*, stopping mysqld, removing ibdata1, restarting, and then reloading the other tables.

Back to the ultimate problem... How to use the data.  First, can we see a sample (a few rows) of the data.  There may be some clues.  How many rows in the table (or lines in the file)?

This may be a case for loading into MyISAM instead of InnoDB; the size for that table will be closer to 8.1GB, plus two indexes, which may add another 5-10GB.  Still unpleasantly tight.

Normalizing the lab names would probably be a big gain.  Suppose you have 10K labs and 100M distances (every lab to every other lab).  Half of those are redundant?  Normalizing lab names would save maybe 50 bites per row -- perhaps half the space?

Or you could get more disk space.

Ponder which suggestion(s) of the above you want to tackle; the let us know what you still need help with.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That makes sense.
I realised the labels are already normalised, so an example of the raw data is:
`1.039324 0 1
1.039324 1 0
1.055924 0 2
1.055924 2 0
1.048772 0 3
1.048772 3 0`
The ultimate goal is to provide a target label and retrieve those closest to it (shortest distance). As you can see, the data above is duplicate (distances 0&1 and 1&0 are equal). I thought the index search would be faster that way, is that true? This was it only has to search one column, as opposed to searching the target in Label1 and Label2. Also, would MyISAM be faster for this?

Comment: I don't see a `SPATIAL` index; do you have such?  What version of MySQL are you running?  Haven't you precomputed all the distances?  What do you mean by "raw data" = "1.039324 0..."?  Sorry, but I seem to be getting lost.

Comment: The version is 5.5.55-0+deb8u1. SPATIAL probably doesn't make sense, since distance is precomputed, right? The table is a representation of a 20K by 20K matrix. So two columns are labels, one column is their distance. This means around 200M rows (some label pairs don't have a distance). Not knowing MySQL well, I wonder what the best solution is. I ultimately care about the speed of a "SELECT WHERE" query, with the results sorted by the distance. I won't be inserting data at all, besides the initial LOAD. Would MyISAM be better suited for the SELECT WHERE speeds, on a table with many rows?

Comment: If it is just 2 labels and a distance, get rid of `id`.  Instead make it `PRIMARY KEY(label1, label2)` and InnoDB.  That gives you the best speed.  However, there is still a potential problem with disk space.

Comment: I realised I'm using VARCHAR(45) for the labels, when in fact they are numbers. So I'll move to INT(4), which should save some space. I'll also get more disk space, from 50GB to 100GB, just in case. Thank you for the advice on the primary keys, I will do that. Do I need to define any additional indexes, or does primary key already do that for me?

Comment: `INT` is 4 bytes.  If they are are 4-digit numbers, then `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` which is 2 bytes and a range of 0..65,635.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is "required".  If you don't specify one, a hidden 6-byte field is silently provided (in InnoDB).